# how to delete the first word and the last in a column?

Tags: r, string, tidyverse

I am trying to delete the first word and the last word in column `CCGName`, only with tidyverse, in R. The CCG column contains the word "NHS" with the city name followed by "CCG". I want to get rid of the words "NHS" and "CCG". Is there a way to do this only with tidyverse?

This is my sample of data:

```
structure(list(SiteType = c(111, 111, 111, 111, 111, 111, 111, 
111, 111, 111), `Call Date` = c("18/03/2020", "18/03/2020", "18/03/2020", 
"18/03/2020", "18/03/2020", "18/03/2020", "18/03/2020", "18/03/2020", 
"18/03/2020", "18/03/2020"), Gender = c("Female", "Female", "Female", 
"Female", "Female", "Female", "Female", "Female", "Female", "Female"
), AgeBand = c("0-18 years", "0-18 years", "0-18 years", "0-18 years", 
"0-18 years", "0-18 years", "0-18 years", "0-18 years", "0-18 years", 
"0-18 years"), CCGCode = c("E38000004", "E38000009", "E38000020", 
"E38000023", "E38000029", "E38000010", "E38000030", "E38000035", 
"E38000008", "E38000025"), CCGName = c("NHS Barking and Dagenham CCG", 
"NHS Bath and North East Somerset CCG", "NHS Brent CCG", "NHS Bromley CCG", 
"NHS Canterbury and Coastal CCG", "NHS Bedfordshire CCG", "NHS Castle Point and Rochford CCG", 
"NHS City and Hackney CCG", "NHS Bassetlaw CCG", "NHS Calderdale CCG"
), `April20 mapped CCGCode` = c("E38000004", "E38000231", "E38000020", 
"E38000244", "E38000237", "E38000010", "E38000030", "E38000035", 
"E38000008", "E38000025"), `April20 mapped CCGName` = c("NHS Barking and Dagenham CCG", 
"NHS Bath and North East Somerset, Swindon and Wiltshire CCG", 
"NHS Brent CCG", "NHS South East London CCG", "NHS Kent and Medway CCG", 
"NHS Bedfordshire CCG", "NHS Castle Point and Rochford CCG", 
"NHS City and Hackney CCG", "NHS Bassetlaw CCG", "NHS Calderdale CCG"
), TriageCount = c(35, 9, 21, 11, 11, 27, 12, 12, 6, 9)), row.names = c(NA, 
-10L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"))
```

Comment: The question pretty clearly specifies tidyverse ...

Comment: I think "non-tidyverse" is debatable. The (previously) accepted answer does use base-R functions (`trimws`, `gsub`), but the overall framework is tidyverse-ish (`mutate` + `%>%`)

Comment: how about this - "^\\w+\\s+(.*)\\s+\\w+", '\\1' .  Isn't this as a base R? I just simply see it is indeed a bit challenging to vote for this -

Comment: @BenBolker I got your point.  My  request was to change the question title so that it is less confusing because using only tidyverse means, making use of the functions provided in those packages.  Also, the OP mentioned `Is there a way to do this only with tidyverse?`

Comment: @GaB It is a regex that you are showing.  It is used in `str_replace` and can be `gsub` or `sub`, but `stringr` is a tidyverse package

Comment: @akrun I have changed the question as I see there are a mix of codes from tidy verse and r base. I believe both codes are quite nice and elegant and it makes hard to vote. Hoping it will be okay

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can also try:

```
library(dplyr)
#Code
df <- df %>% mutate(CCGName=trimws(gsub('NHS|CCG','',CCGName)))
```

Output:

```
df$CCGName
 [1] "Barking and Dagenham"         "Bath and North East Somerset"
 [3] "Brent"                        "Bromley"                     
 [5] "Canterbury and Coastal"       "Bedfordshire"                
 [7] "Castle Point and Rochford"    "City and Hackney"            
 [9] "Bassetlaw"                    "Calderdale"
```

You can also reach the same output with next code (many thanks and credit to **@BenBolker**):

```
#Code 2
df <- df %>% mutate(CCGName=str_remove("^NHS\\s+|\\s+CCG$",string = CCGName))
```

Comment: this is really elegant one, Duck. Thank you

Comment: @GaB Always a pleasure helping!

Comment: @BenBolker Tremendously valid Dr. Bolker! I will add that to the solution.

Answer (score 4):

We can use `str_replace` to match the characters after the first word and space, capture as a group and replace with the backreference of the captured group

```
library(dplyr)
library(stringr)
df2 <- df %>% 
      mutate(CCGName = str_replace(CCGName, "^\\w+\\s+(.*)\\s+\\w+", '\\1'))
```

---

Or using `trimws` from `base R`

```
trimws(df$CCGName, whitespace = "\\s*(NHS|CCG)\\s*")
```

NOTE: This uses only `tidyverse` solution as the OP mentioned in the post.  Also, it is a general solution where it can remove any word that are the first and the last

-output

```
df2$CCGName
#[1] "Barking and Dagenham"         "Bath and North East Somerset" "Brent"                        "Bromley"                     
#[5] "Canterbury and Coastal"       "Bedfordshire"                 "Castle Point and Rochford"    "City and Hackney"            
#[9] "Bassetlaw"                    "Calderdale"
```